# Login as root with trying different passwords in php

Tags: php, command-line, authentication, passwords, root

I am trying to change the password. First I have to login as root, but I don't know the exact password so I need to try 3 different passwords. I found a solution as follow, but I can't get into the if statement. If the first password is not correct I want to try another one. I left if condition empty because i tried several things and neither of them worked.

```
if (!$ssh->login('ntsysadm', 'ABCD123')) {
    echo" Login Failed to server". $iplist[$i];
}else{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Connected to ".$iplist[$i];
    echo "<br>";
    $ssh->write("su - root\n");
    $ssh->read('Password:');
    $ssh->write("ABCD123\n");
    if (  ) {
        $ssh->write("su - root\n");
        $ssh->read('Password:');
        $ssh->write("ABC123\n");
        if (  ) {
            $ssh->write("su - root\n");
            $ssh->read('Password:');
            $ssh->write("ABC1234\n");} }
            $ssh->read('#');
            $ssh->write("passwd ".$_POST['username']."\n");
            $ssh->read('password:');
            $ssh->write($_POST['newpassword']."\n");
            $ssh->read('password:');
            $ssh->write($_POST['newpassword']."\n");
            echo $logDetail = $ssh->read('successfully.');
            echo "<br>";
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['fullname']."','".$idlabuser."','".$serverId."','".$command."','".$datetime."','".$logDetail."') ");
    }
```

Comment: You have some weird code formatting! It's hard to read like that...

Comment: Thank you for editing, Class.

Comment: Instead of multiple IF statements you would be better off with a loop. In terms of your first IF not getting you any further, add some print statements to see the progress and try putting the result of $ssh->login into a variable to see what it is really returning

Answer (score 0):

```
$passwords = array('pass1', 'pass2', 'pass3');

if (!$ssh->login('ntsysadm', 'ABCD123')) {
   echo "Login failed.";
   return;
}
//No need to use else
foreach($pass in $passwords) {
   $ssh->write("su root \n");
   $ssh->write(sprintf("%s \n", $pass);
   if(strstr($ssh->HowIsThisFunctionCalled, 'Logged in'))
      echo sprintf('Password %s is correct.', $pass);
    else
      echo sprintf('Password %s is not correct.', $pass);
}
```

Replace 'HowIsThisFunctionCalled' with the function, that reads out the whole terminal text or last message, pretty sure this exists in PHPSECLIB.

Comment: I could not find that function. I only know how to use $ssh->read('x'), it reads line till x and if there is no "x" in line it does not work.